# Python 2.7.3 | Created a list and tried to append it to itself, this is the result I got, could some please explain me what's happening with it?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I've created a list in python,

```
 list1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

and tried to append it tp itself,

```
 list1.append(list1)
```

this is what i've got, it's kind of never ending!
could someone please explain me what is happening?

```
 >>> list1=[1,2,3,4]
 >>> list1.append(list1)
 >>> list1
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> len(list1)
     5
 >>> len(list1[4])
     5
 >>> print list1[4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> print list1[4][4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> print list1[4][4][4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> print list1[4][4][4][4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> print list1[4][4][4][4][4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> print list1[4][4][4][4][4][4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> print list1[4][4][4][4][4][4][4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> print list1[4][4][4][4][4][4][4][4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
 >>> print list1[4][4][4][4][4][4][4][4][4]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
```

that's never ending. 
Thank You

Comment: @alko,
I dont know that's referred as Circular reference ! But my question is not about [...] !

Comment: dear editors, kindly check the question before editing, my question is not about what is [...] , the question is why ? why is this happening?. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Names in Python are pointers to objects. In this case

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

you create a new `list` object with 4 `int` values in, and assign that to the name `lst`. Next

```
>>> lst.append(lst)
```

you add a new item to the end of your list; a pointer to the list itself. This creates the circular reference, that Python prints as `[...]`. This is because the last item in `lst` points to `lst`, in which the last item points to `lst`, in which...

If you want to append the *content* of the list to your list, you need to copy the object, which you can do with a slice:

```
>>> lst.append(lst[:])
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Another way append the contents of the list to itself is with `lst.extend(lst)` which would result in `lst` becoming `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]` which I suspect is what the OP wants to happen.